# How to show dialog with searching list using LWUIT?

Tags: list, java-me, lwuit

I need to show the dialog with searching list while user pressing the button. How to do it with LWUIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [link](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2008/06/lightweight-text-input-in-lwuit.html). Here clearly said how to do this in the `Form`. Same thing you have to do on the `Dialog`. Show the `Dialog` while clicking the button. So you have add the `actionListener` for this button. See this sample,

```
Button button = new Button("Button");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    // Do here for searching list. Refer that link.
    dialog.show();
  }
```